# watchOS 2 Beta 3 unable to run app from Xcode Beta 3 - shows infinite loading

Tags: ios9, watchos-2, xcode7-beta3, watchos-2-beta3, ios-9-beta3

I am trying to run a very basic watch kit app on the actual watch paired to the iPhone without any network operations or other async stuff just a hello world app but it never launches the app, all I am able to see is a infinite loading animation for some minutes and then the app crashes.

**Xcode version   - 7 Beta 3**

**iOS version     - 9 Beta 3**

**watchOS version - 2 Beta 3**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it up and running by referring to this thread below,

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4994

Steps are as below,

1. Run app on device from xcode. Wait for loading daisy on watch
2. Force quit app. (Hold friends button until power options displays, then hold friends button again until app closes.)
3. Stop debugging on xcode
4. exit xcode (do not reboot/restart xcode)
5. run app on watch. It should run now.
6. if this does not work start from step 1 again.

Thanks to cmhiggins1 user on Apple Developer portal.